# Complex Active-Relation active relation Rails Join Query with multiple relational tables

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a user model that can "follow" some tags

```
User
  has_many :tag_followings 
  has_many :tags, :through => :tag_followings
```

Then I have some articles that have also some tags attached.

```
Article
  has_many :tag_attachings
  has_many :tags, :through => :tag_attachings
```

tag_attaching is a join table that has fields of: user_id and tag_id
and tag_following is a join table that has fields of: article_id and tag_id

- I'm using Rich Many to Many relations(join table have an id)

I'm trying to find an efficient way to find **articles** that have tags that the user is following.

Best practices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using **:include** It should help out significantly, as it will eager load records from the associated table(s).

```
User
  has_many :tag_followings 
  has_many :tags, :through => :tag_followings, :include => [:article]

Article
  has_many :tag_attachings
  has_many :tags, :through => :tag_attachings, :include => [:user]
```

Your statement to retrieve the data, might look like:

```
User.find(1).tags.collect { |t| t.article.id }
```

The executed from your log/development.log should go from:

```
User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT users.* FROM users WHERE (users.id = 1) LIMIT 1
Tag Load (1.2ms) SELECT tags.* FROM tags WHERE (users.tag_id =1)
Article Load (3.2ms) SELECT articles.* FROM articles WHERE (articles.tag_id = 1)
Article Load (3.2ms) SELECT articles.* FROM articles WHERE (articles.tag_id = 3)
Article Load (3.2ms) SELECT articles.* FROM articles WHERE (articles.tag_id = 7)
```

to:

```
User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT users.* FROM users WHERE (users.id = 1) LIMIT 1
Tag Load (1.2ms) SELECT tags.* FROM tags WHERE (users.tag_id =1)
Article Load (3.2ms) SELECT articles.* FROM articles WHERE (articles.tag_id IN (1,3,7))
```

Comment: Hello Paul. Great portfolio! Thanks for introducing me to eager loading!  when I'm running @articles = User.find(1).topics.map { |t| t.articles } the output is not the same as if i had run @articles = Article.find(all). After inspection on the console i found out that the output of the your solution has one more bracket: [[#<Article id: 1, user_id: 2, title: "test">]] and the original:
[#<Article id: 1, user_id: 2, title: "test">]. Do you have any idea how to overcome as my partial cannot render the new variable:undefined method `model_name' for Array:Class

Comment: How are you presenting your output in your partial?

Comment: my index file looks like that <%= render :partial => @articles%> and then the parcial: <%=  link_to_unless_current h(article.title), article %> <%=   h(article.body)  %>